# Updating ALL SOLine items unit prices dynamically when a new SOLine is added

Tags: acumatica

I have a stored procedure that's called by a PXAction. I know it's against Acumatica's best practices to use a stored procedure, but I have yet find an alternative solution for my goal. The stored procedure evaluates each line item and the price class it's associated with depending on the breakQuantity that determines the unit price. If multiple items belong to the same price class == or exceed the break quantity the unit price is reduced.

What I started with was a row updating

```
 protected virtual void SOLine_RowUpdating(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
        SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;
        formalizeOrderTotal(row);
    }
```

then in my formalizeOrderTotal function it performed a foreach loop on `SOLine in lines.Select()` to add up order quantity. As a test i just tried adding up all order quantities and applying it to every line item. This only updated after refreshing which negates the purpose of moving the stored procedure to a c# function/Acumatica event handler.

If anyone has some recommendations a good approach to updating all line items in cache it would be greatly appreciated if you could provide some input.

Comment: 'This only updated after refreshing', you mean after refreshing the screen/Grid?

Comment: You are correct! Sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh(); will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();` which will ask the grid to refresh itself. In this example, I am setting each line quantity to the number of SOLines present in the grid.

```cs
using PX.Data;
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{

    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        protected virtual void SOLine_RowUpdating(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
        {
            SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;
            formalizeOrderTotal(row);
        }

        private void formalizeOrderTotal(SOLine row)
        {
            foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
            {
                if(line.Qty == Base.Transactions.Select().Count)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                line.Qty = Base.Transactions.Select().Count;
                Base.Transactions.Update(line);
                Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll try now!

Comment: it worked out! I'm going to try to play with the RequestRefresh() to try to apply price updates. Thanks Simon.